# What's wrong with my cronjob syntax, I'm trying to use a backtick (`)?

Tags: cron, syntax

Here's what I'd like to automate:

```
00 08 * * * psql -Uuser database < query.sql | mail somone@null.com -s "query for `date +%Y-%m-%dZ%I:%M`"
```

Here's the error message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Apart from the giving error consider to put this in a schell script. It will pretend the crontab to be clumsy and you can add comments and config to your script file.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

From [crontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab):

> The  ``sixth''  field  (the  rest of the line) specifies the
>   command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up
>   to a newline or % character, will be executed  by  /bin/sh
>   or  by  the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the
>   crontab file.  Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped
>   with  backslash (),  will  be  changed into newline characters,
>   and all data after the first % will be sent to the command as
>   standard input. There is no way to
>   split a  single command line onto multiple lines, like the shell's
>   trailing "\".

Just add backslashes before % signs:

```
00 08 * * * psql -Uuser database < query.sql | mail somone@null.com -s "query for `date +\%Y-\%m-\%dZ\%I:\%M`"
```

Answer (score 15):

To resolve the issue **escape your % characters**. `date +%Y-%m-%d` should be `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`

Unfortunately this answer is a little late but the issues is not PATH or backticks - the issue is simply that **the percent character '%' is a special character used to denote a NEWLINE or an STDIN in crontab entries**.

This conflicts with the formatting input of the `date` command. As such a command that includes: `date +%Y-%m-%d` will be interpreted as:

`date
Y-
m-
d`

Answer (score 6):

I had a lot of problems with backticks also.
Sometimes you need more than one occurrence of quotes and backticks.
Just replace them for $().

Example:

```
export NOW=`date`
by
export NOW=$(date)
```

-Gilson Soares

Comment: +1 This is the favoured syntax nowadays anyway.

Comment: but it has nothing to do with the user's question.

Comment: of course it has, its about backsticks, read the question again.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to realize the backticks were breaking my crons - I've started using $() in all my scripts now too

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with backsticks.
A terrible thing is that cron DO NOT see the PATH, and you MUST tell cron "what PATH is ?" over and over in the cron scripts.

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
* * * * * /your/script/here
```

And I am in favour of writing the command in a file instead of passing the command literally in the cron line. It is much more elegant to have

```
* * * * * /your/script/here
```

than

```
* * * * * perl -e '$@#$@$%%@' | grep -e '@#$@$#$@' | sed s/asfdf/asdfa/
```

these line can go inside one file, chmod +x file, and this file to be invoked.