# Rsync not working: If trying to log the output of the Rsync to other file after successful completion of cron job

Tags: linux, cron, rsync

I was trying to execute the below on my linux terminal and it was working fine by creating the backup of the source file at a given location + a log file was getting created with timestamp to the name of the log file.

```
rsync -av --delete /home/root/Desktop/Test/ /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/ /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/zz_crontab_logs/`date +\%F_%H-%M-%S-%N`-test1.log
```

But when I am running the same as a `crontab` as given below the I am not getting any output at all. Neither the backup of the source file nor the log file.

```
30 11,22 * * * rsync -av --delete /home/root/Desktop/Test/ /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/ /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/zz_crontab_logs/`date +\%F_%H-%M-%S-%N`-test1.log
```

and if i am just trying below command in `cron` with out the creating the log file it working fine.

```
30 11,22 * * * rsync -av --delete /home/root/Desktop/Test/ /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/
```

Can some one help on this please.

Comment: Hi HBruijn, I don't think this is a duplicate question as the other question that you marked here seems its no way related to Rsync. I have also added some more inputs to the question and the description. Please check the same.

Comment: Is your question supposed to be about `cron` or `rsync`? If your question is about `rsync` then reproduce the problem without involving `cron` and update your question, then it can be reopened. If your question is about `cron` then it surely looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Hi, my question is about why `rsync` not working properly when trying to with `cron`?, but rest of the `cron` jobs are working fine. Hence wanted help to fix it. I have also updated the question body with the same details.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/84430/whats-wrong-with-my-cronjob-syntax-im-trying-to-use-a-backtick), percent signs need to be escaped.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to review the output/error from the attempt to run the job. You may need to determine why the error output from cron isn't being emailed to you.

Comment: Hi Royce,  when I tried cron with the below(first part to create the back up of the source file) is working ------------    30 11,22 * * * rsync -av --delete /home/root/Desktop/Test/ 
/home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/                -----------------  The problem is only when I am tring to include --------------    /home/root/auto_backups/My_Programs/zz_crontab_logs/`date +\%F_%H-%M-%S-%N`-test1.log     ------------- to the first part.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. Answer updated.